# Login Credentials for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login

I have downloaded 18.04 TLS .ova file and deployed it as a VM in my ESXi host. Not sure on the username/pwd. Couldn't find any readme file.
Could someone share these details.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu cloud images, as other cloud images, are provided with a no-pass user. This allows only ssh access to the VM.

You should create a ssh key pair (http://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) and pass the public key through the hypervisor when instantiating the VM.

Then, login using `ssh -i pathToPrivateKey ubuntu@machineaddress`.